# connecting NOX android emulator to windows VPN (application) settings

Tags: android, android-emulator, localhost

I start Using NOX android emulator and I realized my Ip Address is not affected by my windows VPN application setting.
and I'm not in circumstances to download a VPN for NOX android emulator.
is there any way to fix that?
I'm using Psiphon-3 VPN.